# Parsing parameters via FLAGS to Tensorflow app to launch parallel jobs

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, tensorflow, argparse, python-multiprocessing

I have a runnable `main.py` file built with **tensorflow flags** for parsing args which works just fine and resemble common tensorflow tutorials:

```
flags = tf.flags
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS

flags.DEFINE_string('foo1', "", 'doc foo1')
flags.DEFINE_integer('foo2', 0, 'doc foo2')
flags.DEFINE_integer('foo3', 0, 'doc foo3')

def main(_):
   do something using FLAGS

if __name__ == '__main__':
   tf.app.run(main)
```

Now I would like to launch this main in parallel passing different parameters as flags. I tried creating a different script `main_all.py` which is supposed to launch the main with different parameters but I can't figure out what's the proper way to pass the parameters. This is what I've tried:

```
 from multiprocessing import Pool
 import tensorflow as tf
 from main import main

 app_run = partial(tf.app.run, main=main, foo1="foo1")
 foo2 = [1, 2]
 foo3 = [3, 4]

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     with Pool(2) as pool:
         pool.map(app_run, zip(foo2,foo3,))
```

This doesn't work because `FLAGS` are created only during the import of main and not when calling the `tf.app.run` parsing the additional `args` into flags?!.
Is there a clean workaround or maybe it's better to use a bash script?

Any ideas on how to solve it?

thanks in advance